# Qt reads pictures from excel

Tags: excel, qt

everyone. Now I need to use Qt to read excel files and there are some pictures in cells. I wrote these codes as follow to finish the job.

```
QAxObject *pExcel = new QAxObject("Excel.Application");    
if (pExcel == NULL || pExcel->isNull())
{
    return;
}
pExcel->dynamicCall("SetVisible(bool)", false);
QAxObject *pWorkbooks = pExcel->querySubObject("WorkBooks");
if (pWorkbooks == NULL || pWorkbooks->isNull())
{
    delete pExcel;
    pExcel = nullptr;
    return;
}
QAxObject *pWorkbook = pWorkbooks->querySubObject("Open(QString&)", qstrExcelPath);
if (pWorkbook == NULL || pWorkbook->isNull())
{
    delete pExcel;
    pExcel = nullptr;
    return;
}
QAxObject *pWorksheets = pWorkbook->querySubObject("WorkSheets");
if (pWorksheets == NULL || pWorksheets->isNull())
{
    delete pExcel;
    pExcel = nullptr;
    return;
}
QAxObject *pWorksheet = pWorksheets->querySubObject("Item(int)", 1);
if (pWorksheet == NULL || pWorksheet->isNull())
{
    delete pExcel;
    pExcel = nullptr;
    return;
}

QAxObject *pUsedRange = pWorksheet->querySubObject("UsedRange");
if (NULL == pUsedRange || pUsedRange->isNull())
{
    delete pExcel;
    pExcel = nullptr;
    return;
}

QVariant varExcelInfo = pUsedRange->dynamicCall("Value");
```

`varExcelInfo` can read strings correctly but can not read pictures. How can I do to read pictures from excel files? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pictures are stored in [Shape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape) objects in the [Worksheet.Shapes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.shapes) property.

I can't see a way to directly read the image file, but you might be able to transfer it via the clipboard using the [Shape.CopyPicture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.copypicture) method to copy it onto the clipboard; then use the Qt [QClipboard::image](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html#image) function to copy the image into a [QImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But there are two problems in the method. Firstly, I can't map cell to picture. In other word, I don't know which cell the picture came from, because I want to read a picture that comes from spcific cell. Secondly, the copied picture is not clear and has poor quality.